# Laravel 5.2 - show first image from database

Tags: php, image, view, laravel-5

I have table `photos` in my database where my images are stored. In one view user can see all of them, but in the other I want only one image to be seen, first one. How to set it so only the first image is displayed, not all of them?

This is my code.

**View**

```
@foreach($business->photos as $photo)

    <img src="{{ url($photo->thumbnail_path) }}" class="img-thumbnail">

@endforeach
```

**ProfileController**

```
public function profile($id)
{
  $user = User::findOrFail($id);

  return view('business.profile', compact('user'));
}
```

**Photo.php**

```
public function business()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Business');
}


public function baseDir()
{
    return 'images/';
}

public function setNameAttribute($name)
{
    $this->attributes['name'] = $name;

    $this->path = $this->baseDir() . '/' . $name;

    $this->thumbnail_path = $this->baseDir() . '/tn' . $name;
}
```

**PhotosController**

```
public function store($id, AddPhotoRequest $request)
{
  $business = Business::fidOrFail($id);

  $photo = $request->file('photo');

  (new AddPhotoToBusiness($business, $photo))->save();
}
```

Comment: can u show your model and controller?

Comment: by the way you can use  Model::where(" your query",condition,"" )->first();

Comment: On profile want to display just first photo, but on other still have option to show all images.

Comment: please post your complete code

Comment: you can use $business->photos->first(); it is not tested but it should work

Comment: Then I get Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: you can pass another variable to view with first image.

Comment: Like this $business->first()->photos as $photo I get first result, but not result owned by user. Can I pass id somehow, so it shows first photo but one that is owned by user?

Comment: once i had the same problem you look at this example $experience = \App\User::find(Auth::id())->experiences()->first();

Comment: you can pass another variable to view where you are passing photos to view....a simple and dirty suggestion....or you do like this $bussiness->photos[0]->thumbnail_image

Comment: Tried both, on both I get Trying to get property of non-object ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107354/discussion-between-adnan-mumtaz-and-kornor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**:

```
@if(count($business->photos))
    <img src="{{ url($business->photos[0]->thumbnail_path) }}" class="img-thumbnail" alt="">
@else
    <img src="{{ URL::asset('/img/no-image.png') }}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

In your views you are getting an array.if you use first() in foreach you will get that error.

for example:

```
@foreach($business->photos as $photo)
    <img src="{{ url($photo->thumbnail_path) }}" class="img-thumbnail"
         alt="">
@endforeach

->here $business->photos holding an array.in that if you use $business->photos->first() .it shows error
```

So use a php tag in views

```
<?php  $x=$business->photos->first();  ?>
```

if you use this then it shows only one row

and then bind which value you need that is present in $x variable.