# how to get just first image on laravel

Tags: laravel

i already tried (i tried) ([Laravel 5.2 - show first image from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222979/laravel-5-2-show-first-image-from-database))

but i got value "rumahnya= n  rumahnya= t  rumahnya= I" on photo_rumah

```
controller
public function index()
    {
        //
        $data   = $this->dataRumah();
        // dd($data);
        return view('panelD.data_rumah',[
            'data' => $data,
        ]);
    }
    // get data
    public function dataRumah(){
        $data = DB::table('datarumah')->get();
        foreach($data as $keys => $value){
            $photoRumah = DB::table('photorumah')->where('id_rumah', '=', $value->id_rumah)->get();
            $value->DataPhoto   = $photoRumah;
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

```
blade

     <a href="#"><img src="{{asset('././././assets/PhotoRumah/'.$itemPhoto->photo_rumah[0])}}" alt=""></a>
       //when i echo i just got value "rumahnya= n  rumahnya= t  rumahnya= I" on photo_rumah
```

Comment: Don't just make a request!

Comment: Please show us your controller code as well

Comment: already edit my dd to controller
#sorry

Comment: solved [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51320749/how-to-show-only-one-image-in-the-index-page-in-laravel-5-6)
Thank You,
sorry for that questiong still learning 